# How to check the given input is binary number or not?

Tags: python

I need to write a logic to print message like `it's a binary` or `it's not a binary`

Input 1 : `100001`

Input 2 : `001`

Input 3 : `101`

**I have written below code :**

```
n=str(input('enter the number'))

if len(n) == 8:
   print("it's a binary")
else:
   print("it's not a binary")
```

Seems like this is not a right approach any other way to identify

Output 1 : It's a binary

Output 2 : It's a binary

Output 3 : It's a binary

`101 , 001` -> if padded with zero from left then it becomes 8 digit binary number

Invalid binary numbers : `254 , 66 , 72 , 1056`

Binary should contain only `1` and `0`

Comment: So a length of 8 characters is your definition of a binary number???

Comment: What are the expected outputs for the three given inputs? As far as I can tell, each can reasonably represent a binary number.

Comment: You could use regex ‘[0-1]{8}’ checking for an 8 digits only containing zeros or ones

Comment: What about leading zeros?

Comment: Can you give an example of an invalid binary number?

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem : question updated

Comment: As you said `Binary should contain only 1 and 0` so just write code for that, not about its length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using sets, it should make it easy. A set will take the unique items of your string, thus for a binary number you can match for 0 and 1 as strings in a set.

The "pipe" or the "or" operation will join the sets and if there's anything more than the set of zeroes and ones, it'll fail.

Notice it'll be true on an empty input, for that check for `If text and ...`. (`(set()|{'0', '1'}) == {'0', '1'}`]

Alternatively [`set.issubset()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) should be a replacement for the `==` operator, if that suits you better.

```py
text = input()
if (set(text) | {'0', '1'}) == {'0', '1'}:
    print("binary")
```

Comment: can use `set(text).issubet({'0', '1'})`

Comment: @Peter Badida : Can you explain what is the if Statement doing in detail

Comment: This might not matter in any reasonable application, but I prefer short-circuited iteration over using `set` here. If `text` is something ridiculous like `string.printable * 10 ** 6`,  this is one million times slower than calling `all(c in "01" for c in text)`.

Comment: @yayaxak320 it takes your input with set() which will make the characters in your input unique (for binary being only 0 and 1 chars + a space if you include any (`text.replace(' ', '')`), then does an "or" operation i.e. joins the two sets, so it's either `{'0', '1'}` set or larger and then it compares to `{'0', '1'}` which will be true for binary numbers without spaces or an empty input string.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the `int` as a `str` and check if it only contains `'0'` and `'1'`:

```
n = input()
if not n: # So n is different from '' (empty string)
    print('Not binary')
    return
for i in n:
    if (i not in ['0', '1']):
        print('Not binary')
        return
print('Binary')
```

---

Your previous check strategy won't work at all, according to your code:

- `01234567` -> It's a binary
- `0101` -> It's not a binary

---

To check this you can anyway use the `re` Python library (re stands for `regex`, **reg**ular **ex**pression):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('^[0-1]{8}$') # A string made out of 0 and 1 and of lenght 8
if pattern.match(input()):
    print('Binary of lenght 8')
else:
    print('Not a binary of lenght 8')
```

---

If you don't care about lenght, you can use `set`s, a Python's `iterable` class that doesn't admit duplicate elements in it:

```
>>> set(['1', '1', '0'])
{'1', '0'}
>>> set('01011010101010')
{'0', '1'}
```

Then you can write something like this:

```
if set(input()) in [{'0', '1'}, {'0'}, {'1'}]:
    print('Binary')
```

As @azro suggested, a better syntax is using `set` instance method `issubset`, like this:

```
if set(input()).issubset({'0'}, {'1'}):
    print('binary')
```

Comment: Right, I'm just going to edit.

Comment: In you answer you don't need to display the OP wrong code again, just say that length isn't a good argument that's it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, the answer should now be ok.

Comment: `set(input(">>")).issubet({'0', '1'})` is nicer :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be if the string contains either **0** or **1** only then we can conclude it is a binary otherwise not.

```
given_string = input('enter the number')
# set function convert string into set of characters
p = set(given_string)
 
# declare set of '0', '1'
s = {'0', '1'}
 
# check set p is same as set s or set p contains only '0'
# or set p contains only '1'or not, if any one condition
# is true then string is accepted otherwise not accepted
if s == p or p == {'0'} or p == {'1'}:
        print("Yes")
else :
        print("No")
```

Alternatively you can try the `issubset` method of set using the following approach:

```
given_string = input('enter the number')
x = {"0", "1"}
y = set(given_string)
if y.issubset(x): 
      print("Binary")
else:
      print("Not Binary")
```

Comment: use set.issubset `if p.issubset(s):` and wrapping `input` with str is useless ;)

Answer (score 0):

In case to check for an 8 bit binary

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("^([0-1]{8})$")
strings=[
    "00000001",
    "12345678",
    "101",
]
for string in strings:
    if pattern.match(string):
        print(f"{string} is 8-bit binary")
    else:
        print(f"{string} is not 8-bit binary")
```

Output

```
00000001 is 8-bit binary
12345678 is not 8-bit binary
101 is not 8-bit binary
```

In case the binary number can contain any number of zeros and ones or less use

```
"^([0-1]+)$"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as follows:

```
def is_binary(s):
  # bool(s) guards against the case of s = ""
  return bool(s) and all(c in "01" for c in s)

def is_binary2(s):
  try:
    # check if the builtin int type can parse a binary string
    res = int(s, base=2)
    return True
  except:
    return False
```

The first approach checks if all digits are 0 or 1, and takes care of the empty string case. The second approach delegates all of the works to the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

1. Input return a string so the str() is useless
2. Your outputs are wrong.
3. Your code return if a str could be a byte.
4. Here is a code to know if a string is a byte :

```
def is_binary(n:str) -> bool :
    return len(n) = [for i in n if i == "0" or i == "1"]

def is_byte(n:str) -> bool :
    return is_binary(n) and len(n) = 8

print(is_byte(10010110))
-> True
print(is_byte(100a01c0))
-> False
print(is_byte(101))
-> False
```

You can also convert str to set to know if it is a binary number ;)